# Need help with a proof involving nonlinear differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a problem that stated:

If $ae \neq bd$ prove that you can choose 2 constants, h and k, so that the substitution $t= s - h$ , $ x = y - k $ reduce the following equation to a homogeneous equation.
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = F \left(\frac{at+bx+c}{dt+ex+f}\right)$$

I'm unsure about what I'm supposed to be doing here.
Doing all the substitutions I got
$$ \frac{dy}{ds} = F\left(\frac {as -ah+by-bk+c}{ds-dh+ey-ek+f}\right) $$

From this I gathered that if $\displaystyle k = \frac{fa-dc}{ea-db} $ ( Note that I'm not dividing by 0 since I know $ae\neq bd$) and $ \displaystyle h = \frac{c}{a} - \frac{b}{a} \left[\frac{fa - dc}{ea - db}\right] $ then I would have
$$ \frac{dy}{ds} = F\left(\frac{as+by}{ds+ey}\right)$$
With $ v = \frac{s}{y} $ I can write this as $$ G(v) = F(\frac{a+bv}{d+ev}) $$

Which if I understand it correctly would make this a 0 order differential equation, right?
It seem kind of weird that this works regardless of what F is as long as $ ae \neq bd $.

Comment: Well, what does it mean to be homogeneous? Once you see that, the answer becomes evident.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing this is a 0 degree homogeneous equation so $ F( \sigma [\frac{as + by}{ds+ey}]) = F(\frac{as +by}{ds+ey}) $, which is true for this equation, right?

Comment: What is $\sigma$ ?

Comment: The reason $ae \neq bd$ is important is that it keeps the matrix of coefficients non-singular and therefore invertible.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a hint.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation)

Comment: With $\sigma$ I meant to check if F is homogeneous of degree 0, since I already know it can be written as $$ \frac{dy}{ds} = F(y, s) $$. I just define $$ G(y, s) = \frac{as + by}{ds+ey} $$ and look at $$ F(G(y,s)) = F(\frac{as + by}{ds+ey}) = \frac{dy}{ds} $$.

Comment: The point is that $G(y,s)$ is invariant for a rescaling of both variables with a same factor. Therefore so is $F\circ G$ and thus the differential equation is homogeneous. And that is all there is to it.